# How are Dynamics 365 Sales Hub Tables Generated

Tags: dynamics-crm, microsoft-dynamics, dynamics-crm-365

Can someone let me know if Dynamics 365 Sales Hub have a defined list of tables that are used to build it environment?

For example, there an Accounts and Contacts within Customers, see image. I would like to know what tables are used to build Accounts or Contacts. Is there a set table structure used?

[image]

Comment: they are based on the Common Data Model https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/common-data-model/

Comment: Hey Guido, is it possible to download the CDM?

Comment: you can check this repo https://github.com/microsoft/CDM, has also a visual navigator

Comment: Hi Guido, thanks again for reaching out. I have visited the link you just provided. The visual navigator is amazing. Is it possible to view how tables I joined together? For example, how the account table is joined to the appointment table? Does that make sense?

Comment: Another example would be the something like the Account table having a primary key called account_id which might be used to join to say the appointment table on the activityId primary key?

Comment: Not always. In your example Appointment is connected to an Account usually with RegardingObjectId (that can accept other entities like Account, Contact, User,...) so is not only a lookup to Account. Not specified in the model but inside Dynamics 365 you can use also optionalattendees or requiredattendees. ActivityId is also a primary key of the Activities that can include Appointment, Letter, etc etc. If you want to check the model of a Dynamics 365 there are also other tools like the Metadata Browser inside XrmToolBox

Comment: Guido, that is exactly what I need - to have a tool that would allow me to see that the Account table uses the RegardingObjectId to join to other tables. So, are you saying XrmToolBox will allow me to view that join? Sorry, if I'm using the wrong terms here.

Comment: is the appointment table that contains the RegardingObjectId. Yes, with Metadata Browser for XrmToolBox (XrmToolBox is a tool to launch different tools) you can see the column RegardingObjectId details, in the right panel you will find Targets that give you all the other tables accepted by RegardingObjectId.

Comment: I have just installed XrmToolBox. It's quite mind boggling... I have no idea how to use it to view the column RegardingObjectId detail :-(

Comment: Can you provide some guidance on how to use/install the Metadata Browser for XrmToolBox. I found the following link https://github.com/MscrmTools/MsCrmTools.MetadataBrowser

Comment: Guido, don't worry, I have the Metadata Browser now. Thanks

Comment: ok, let me know if this solve your issue, I may write an answer to recap these comments